# Docker nginx server returns 302 to HTTP POST: proxy then fails

Tags: php, proxy

I have a fairly simple Docker setup whereby a `jwilder/nginx-proxy` container sits above an `nginx` container which listens to a `php_fpm`.

All seems well until the website attempts an HTTP `POST` (for a password).  The nginx server returns a `HTTP 302` response.  The next request, for the subsequent "dashboard," gets `HTTP 499`.  The proxy layer says:  "upstream timed out while reading response header from upstream."

Strangely enough, looking at the logs of the actual application-FPM container, I see no reference whatsoever to anything but `index.php!`

(This is strictly a "developer machine" environment ...)

Thoughts?

Comment: This thing has costed me time maaan - I'm using 
1. nginx:stable-alpine
and 
2. devilbox/php-fpm:8.1-mods

Answer (score 0):

As I also answered elsewhere, this is how it turned out:

- The login dialog does an HTTP `POST` to `/login`
- The proxy server got the request, but wound up timing-out hence the `502`.
- The nginx server found that the FPM server process apparently *died,* resulting in a `499` code.  (But apparently the Proxy didn't get that ...)
- The php-FPM server produced **nothing** in its own log-files.  No indication that it ever even got the `/login` request in the first place, and no indication whatever why it died.

What did it turn out to be?  A problem connecting with a back-end database server.  But, finding that out was *pure guesswork.*

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked out...So ths issue was that I had made a mistake with the rewrite configuration for default nginx configuration file. To sort you out stackoverflow style.

Look for this line

> try_files ...

below it add this rewrite regex in condition

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php;
   }
```

adapted from this article from Digital Ocean
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unexpected-302-error-moved-temporarily-after-login-in-my-website